# Undefined method in multiple-exception-catch

Tags: java, exception, catch-block, multi-catch

I have two classes inheriting from `java.lang.Exception`. They both have a method with the same signature `void a(){...}`. They both can be thrown in a code block. If I do:

```
catch (SubException1 | SubException2 e)
    {
        e.a();
    }
```

Then it won't compile because method `a()` does not belong to Exception. Is it a Java language flaw? How should I design my code properly to prevent code redundancy?

Comment: The signature does not matter, is it the same method of some common superclass? Is `a` defined in some common superclass of `SubException1` and `SubException2`?

Comment: You can eliminate redundancy by giving them a common ancestor that has prescribed method `void a()`. Then you can catch the ancestor and call `e.a()`

Comment: When using multicatch, actual type of exception local variable is the closest common supertype, which it looks like it is `Exception` in your case. So it doesn't really matter that `SubException1` has `a()`. You can solve this by having a common supertype with `a()` on both methods, as already was suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you catch multiple exception types in a single catch statement the inferred type of the caught exception is the greatest common denominator of those classes. In your case, the greatest common denominator is `Exception`, which doesn't have the method `void a()`. In order to make it accessible to the catch block you could either extract it to a common base class, or (arguably) more elegantly, define it in an interface that both classes implement:

```
public interface SomeExceptionInterface {
    void a();
}

public class SomeException extends Exception implements SomeExceptionInterface {
    // Implementation...
}

public class SomeException2 extends Exception implements SomeExceptionInterface {
    // Implementation...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a method called `a()`, you need a type that provides that method. A simple solution could be:

```
public class AbstractSubException extends Exception {
    public abstract void a();
}

public class SubException1 extends AbstractSubException {
    @Override public void a() { ... }
}

public class SubException2 extends AbstractSubException {
    @Override public void a() { ... }
}
```

Then you can catch the way you did or (somewhat simpler):

```
catch (AbstractSubException e) {
    e.a();
}
```

Maybe the code for the method `a` is the same in all sub classes. Then you can make it concrete and put the code into the parent class.